# Group and count number of badges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, group-by

A user has_many badges through badge_awardings

I can do

```
@user.badges.count(:group => 'badges.id')
```

Which returns a hash of ids and counts like this

```
{1=>2, 2=>1, 5=>1, 8=>1}
```

But then I have to find the badges again individually to display them.

Is there anyway of returning a hash of badges and their counts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the badges in another step:

```
badge_count = @user.badges.count(:group => 'badges.id')
badges = Badge.find(badge_count.keys)
badges_counted = badges.inject({}){ |h, v| h.update(v => badge_count[v.id]) }
```

Comment: This look useful, but I get `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]=' for 2:Fixnum` after the last command

Comment: My bad, minor semantic error. Check the updated answer, the last row changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
@user.badges.count(:group => [:id, :some_column_name, :another_column_name])
```

This would get you:

```
{[1, 'something', 'other_thing']=>2, [2, 'a', 'b']=>1, ...}
```

Comment: Thank you - this would have been very useful, but I have to do stuff with the badge...